# question about continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

The question is: Assume $f$ is a bounded continuous function in $[a,b)$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. Also assume $f$ is not continuous in $[a,b]$. prove: $f'(x)$ is neither upper bounded nor lower bounded [sorry :(].

Comment: consider $\tan x$

Comment: I don't think this claim is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded and continuous on $[-1,0)$, differentiable in $(-1,0)$, not continuous at $0$. Its derivative is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Take $f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin \frac{1}{b-x} & x < b \\
0 & x = b\end{cases}$. Then $f'(x) = \frac{\cos\left( \frac{1}{x-b}\right) }{{\left( x-b\right) }^{2}}$, which is unbounded above and below.

$f$ is bounded, continuous on $[a,b)$, not continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f'$ exists on $(a,b)$.

Answer to the modified question:

Again, it is not true. Let $f = 1_{[a,b)}$. $f$ is bounded, continuous on $[a,b)$, not continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f'$ exists on $(a,b)$. Clearly $f'$ is bounded above and below on $(a,b)$.

Comment: I had mistake. The question is the opposite.

Comment: It is still not true. See the addition to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

An even easier counterexample is
$$f: [a,0] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0 \\
\sqrt {-x} & 0>x\geq  a\end{cases}$$
where $a<0$.